# Webpack tree shaking with unusued import

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am trying to develop a library similar to Axios for both client and server side.
I was hoping that the tree shaking feature from webpack would help me to remove dead code from imports when used in client side, but it doesn't. Here is a short example of the code:

```
import http from "http";
import https from "https";

export class FetchClient {
    static request(...) { ... }
};

export class FetchServer {
    static request(...) { ... }
}
```

When I only import FetchClient, webpack still includes the code for "http" and "https" in my bundle, which makes the bundle ~100KB larger than expected, eventhough it is not used in this code path.

Also I looked at the code for Axios, it seems they are using conditional **require** instead of **import** (see the adapter code part). Would the trick be to load conditionaly and therfore asynchronously the http and https dependencies? In that case the code would still be in my bundle, which is somethign I would like to avoid.

Note: I am using the TerserPlugin (minimizer),  "sideEffects": false in my packages.json and modules all the way.

EDIT:

I managed to go around my issue, by using the EnvironmentPlugin webpack plugin and splitting my code in 3 files: 2 files containing each implementation (for client and server) and the main file containing the following logic:

```
let adapter = null;
if (process.env.EXEC_ENV === "node") {
    adapter = (await import("./adapter/node.http.js")).default;
}
else if (process.env.EXEC_ENV === "web") {
    adapter = (await import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */"./adapter/window.fetch.js")).default;
}
```

I find it quite strange that webpack is not able to do this by himself, I thought that's what the sideEffects flag was for. Maybe the static analyzer is not smart enough?

Answer (score 0):

`import https from "https";`

Importing like this will import all the files. Since it does not know, there might be some global initialization. Same time HTTP, and HTTPS module will not be available on client-side. So it has to be browsify.

Axios also include `follow-redirects`, which includes both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` module.

Axios:
`transport = isHttpsProxy ? httpsFollow : httpFollow;`

This is not `condition` require, this is a `conditional` return. `adaptor pattern`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was thinking about this code path for the adapter (see getDefaultAdapter() in https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js). At least this way you can clearly do some conditional import (something you cannot do with import, unless you use the asynchronous syntax).